# httpModule in Web Application Project not being called when deployed to IIS

Tags: iis, web-config, iis-express, httpmodule, vs-web-application-project

I am in the process of converting out web site project to a web application project. I've got everything to compile and even publish (long process). However, now that I've got the project "loading" in IIS, the httpModule is not called.

The modules section of web.config looks like this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="ContentWebSite" type="ContentWebSite.ContentWebSite"/>
     </modules>
```

the class of the httpModule starts like this:

```
namespace ContentWebSite
{
   public class ContentWebSite : IHttpModule
   {
      private HttpApplication _Application;
```

What am I missing? Setting a breakpoint in the constructor or the init method of the ContentWebSite class is never hit when I'm running in the context of local IIS. When I run in IIS Express, the breakpoint is hit! How do I get IIS to invoke the httpModule?

TIA,

Comment: I think the module is loading (If I change the type in web.config to ContentWebSite.Content.WebSit, I get an error saying the module can't be loaded). However, the constructor or the Init method are not getting called.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the application pool mode caused your problem.

Application pool mode: classic versus integrated.

[image]

```
<system.webServer><!--for integrated mode-->
    <modules>
      <add name="modulename" type="ContentWebSite.ContentWebSite" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web><!--for classic mode-->
     <httpModules>
      <add name="modulename" type="ContentWebSite.ContentWebSite" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just found another clue: if I run the application in IIS Express, the httpModule is executed! Switching to IIS (which is where the site runs in production), the httpModule is not executed. I checked the application pool, and it is set to Integrated.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638555/httpmodule-in-iis-8-5-not-being-loaded

Comment: Theobald Du - Thanks for the reply. Extensibility Features are already installed on IIS. We have asp.net website projects running in IIS that have httpModules that work perfectly fine. This web application project is just skipping the httpModule.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I got this working by changing the modules add name line to this:

```
<add name="modulename" type="ContentWEbSite.ContentWebsite, appName" />
```

Where appName is the physical name of the DLL generated for the project!